# Using textX instead of text1, text2 etc. needed to select a ListBox item

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make an app in C# which will display a text in a RichTextBox when selecting an item from ListBox.

For this I normally need to define

```
string text1, text2, preview1, preview2;
```

But I need to make that `textX`, `previewX` as the number of contents in ListBox will vary.

How do I do this? Tried `text.X` and `text[X]` but no success.

EDIT: Here's the (roughly-written) code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string word[X] = textBox1.Text;
            string preview[X] = textBox2.Text;
            listBox1.Items.Add(word + ": " + meaning);
        }

        private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            word[X] = listBox1.Index[X].Text();
            richTextBox1.Text = preview[listBox1.Index];
        }
```

Comment: could you show more code?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Without knowing your actual code this sounds to me like you are trying to achieve something with separate variables which you'd normally use an array for. Would that solve your problem here?

Comment: Code added now.